# Problems running a Java program from within PHP

Tags: java, php

I'm writing a PHP script that basically calls a Java program with a string, has Java create a file whose name is that string, and returning that file. Also, it's all midi.

```
$output_file = mt_rand(10000000,99999999) . ".mid";
system("java MCS " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . " " . $output_file . " " . escapeshellarg($_POST['message']));
header('Content-type: audio/midi');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.mid"');
readfile($output_file);
unlink($output_file);
```

Only problem is I get this problem: Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.

I have tried using `exec`. The script completes but the java program doesn't run.

Comment: Try using `exec` with output redirection for the command to file, like `java MCS ... > outputlog.txt` and post the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the OS shell (`bash` on *nix and `cmd` on Windows) as it probably does a better job of configuring the environment correctly. Try something like this:

```
$output_file = mt_rand(10000000,99999999) . ".mid";
$platformshell = "/bin/sh -c "; // on windows use "cmd /c "
system($platformshell . "\"java MCS " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . " " . $output_file . " " . escapeshellarg($_POST['message']) . "\"");
header('Content-type: audio/midi');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.mid"');
readfile($output_file);
unlink($output_file);
```

EDIT: on Ubuntu, might want to explicitly use `/bin/bash`, since they insist on doing things like linking `sh` to `dash` (which among other truly annoying things doesn't natively support *pushd* and *popd*, breaking shell calls that worked perfectly for years and years...). If you still get working directory problems you can put a `pushd <required directory>` before the *java* call on *nix machines (not sure what the Windows syntax would be: might want to make a *cmd* script that takes care of all the working directory bits and just call that).

EDIT: ignore my rant at the end of the comment above. I did this a couple of years ago, and had to use `exec`:

```
$r = array();
    exec($this->config->item("java_path") . ' -cp ' . $this->config->item("java_base") . '\databasebackups.jar;' . $this->config->item("java_base") . '\requirements.jar ' . $startdate . $enddate . ' com.blah.blah.LastTransactionReport --user sa --password ' . $this->config->item("ms_password") . ' --dburl ' . $this->config->item("ms_url"), $r);
```

My configuration included the full path to the Java runtime and the directory that the jar files were in (this was using Code Igniter) and the output was saved into the `$r` array. Try something like that and let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately none of this worked. I'm not really sure what you mean by using pushd, either.